# More select box appearing after edits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a new select box appearing after edit. The model that I modified in the edit is another model using fields_for option.

Someone mentioned that I had the problem with the new and create actions in the controller.

the current controller:

```
def new
  @print = Print.new
end

def create
  @print = Print.new(params[:print])
  @print.user_id = current_user.id
  if @print.save
    redirect_to print_path(@print), :flash => { :success => "Successfully created your Print Order." }
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end

def edit
  @print = Print.find(params[:id])
  @print.blackwhites.build
end
```

The fields_for that edit data from the model:

```
  def index

  def new
    @blackwhite = Blackwhite.new
  end

  def create
    @blackwhite = Blackwhite.new(params[:blackwhite])
    @blackwhite.print_id = @print.id
  end

  def update
    @blackwhite = Blackwhite.find(params[:id])
  end

  def show
    @blackwhite = Blackwhite.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @blackwhite = Blackwhite.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Edit:

Fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I see:

```
def create
  @blackwhite = Blackwhite.new(params[:blackwhite])
  @blackwhite.print_id = @print.id
  render :action => 'new'   <<<< ?????
end
```

Try

```
redirect_to print_path(@print)
```

That would be the typical default thing to do,  show the data that just got created,  or in your nested case, show the parent of the record that just got created.  All you really need to do is STOP rendering the new action after you create,  that's NOT right!

Comment: Oh yes. that comes after else statement.